# js compression issue when loading image for www in unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I have a compression issue when im trying to import an image (into unity) from the server.

I have a jpg image called "glass" in the resources folder within unity and i want this image to be replaced by an image on a server at runtime. I found this script http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html for importing the images and assigned it to my "glass" image.

The only problem is that the compression of the image is (NPOT) RGBA Compressed DXT5, while the code in the link states that jpg's are being compressed as DXT1.

Can any of you tell me what im doing wrong?

```
#pragma strict
    // random url link from google
    // and DXT compress them at runtime
    var url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yaqe1qesQ8c/maxresdefault.jpg";

    function Start () {
        // Create a texture in DXT1 format
        GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
        while(true) {
            // Start a download of the given URL
            var www = new WWW(url);

            // wait until the download is done
            yield www;

            var Texture_1: Texture2D;
            Texture_1 = Resources.Load("glass");

            // assign the downloaded image to the main texture of the object
            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(Texture_1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what's wrong with DXT5?

Comment: and what is the problem? do you have any error log? or is the image just not showing?

Comment: Hello Nika,

The image is showing in the inspector, but stays black within the assets folder and when added to a gameobject as a texture.

Secondly, i want to add more images in this way and some of those images are added to a cubemap/skybox. I get a warning that the alpha makes the image incompatible with hdr.

I also find it strange that the JS is converting it to a dxt5. That means that the code isn't working somehow and if i want to change the compression later on in the project (for whatever reason) then i can't do that with this code. 

thanks for the response!

Comment: I think this is a server-side issue. try to upload images on the server in png format. or look into the server set-up. it's common practice to serve files in compressed formats (sometimes overriding the compression like in your case). If you have access to server administration try to change the compression the files are served with. (I'm not a back-end expert but I've been in a similar situation and server tweaking solved it)

Comment: I tried uploading a png, but i get the same dxt5 compression. But if you upload a png it should make it a dxt5 right? I'm also no back-end expert but i don't think the server is compressing the files, because i can download them without compression issues

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests, and it looks like a Unity bug to me.

In contradiction with the documentation, it does matter what was the texture format before LoadImageIntoTexture, and if texture is compressed, it is always DXT5.

Here is what happening:

- If you load image into an previously uncompressed texture(RGB24 for example), the resulting format is uncompressed RGB24 or ARGB32 (depending whether or not the image contains alpha channel).
- If you load image into a previously compressed texture, the result will be a texture compressed with DXT5. It does not matter whether or not the image has an alpha channel.
- If you use www.texture instead of www.LoadImageIntoTexture, the result is always uncompressed texture (RGB24 or ARGB32).
- Calling Texture.Compress() manually on uncompressed texture gives correct format (DXT1 or DXT5 depending on alpha channel).

Anyway, here is a workaround: instead of using

```
 www.LoadImageIntoTexture(Texture_1);
```

use

```
 // Load uncompressed RGB24 or ARGB32 depending on alpha channel
 Texture_1 = www.texture;
 // Compress with the correct format
 Texture_1.Compress(true);
```

The result will be DXT1 for JPG or DTX5 for PNG, as it should to be.

P.S. This is not unique to JS, happens in C# too.

Comment: I replaced the loadImageIntoTexture code with your workaround, but nothing seems to happen. I also used a different original image and ran it with and without a dxt1 override, but nothing.